# presentModalViewController not calling viewWillRotate, didRotateToInterface

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad

I have a UIViewController which presents a modal view controller and when I rotate the modal view controller it does not call the viewWilLRotate, didRotateToInterface, and willAnimateToInterface... of the UIViewController presenting this modal view. Why is this? This causes the view of my iphone to be messed up if I change the orientation of the modal view controller and dismiss it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In parent viewController, check if

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
```

returns YES or not or in view hierarchy check it. You have to return Yes or orientation that you want.